# Representation of -40 in 8bit computer using 2's complement

Tags: computer-architecture

What is the representation of -40 in a 8bit computer using 2's complement intiger?

Comment: The answer can be easily found by following the procedure described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_to_two's_complement_representation).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP showed no attempt

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 40 in binary is 101000.

The 8-bit representation is obtained by zero-padding: 00101000.

The one's complement of this is obtained by inverting the bits: 11010111.

To obtain the two's complement, we simply add 1: 11011000.